Why is Chalmer's naturalistic dualism not a form of non-reductive physicalism?
Related to a question on physicalism and a priori (Do physicalists think a priori knowledge exists?), I alleged that David Chalmers naturalistic dualism is a non-reduction physicalist position. It is a fair challenge to construe naturalistic dualism as a form of physicalism. While I understand the broad thrusts of conceivability (which I personally don't believe entails possibility) undermining physicalist explanations of consciousness, it still seems to me that his form of dualism is a non-reductive form of physicalism. In no way is Chalmers an idealist, and he certainly doesn't resort to leaving naturalism, and from what I can understand of his work, it seems he alleges that the mental is a property of the physical, a point that seems to be echoed by WP:

Chalmers characterizes his view as "naturalistic dualism": naturalistic because he believes mental states supervene "naturally" on physical systems (such as brains); dualist because he believes mental states are ontologically distinct from and not reducible to physical systems. He has also characterized his view by more traditional formulations such as property dualism. (empahsis mine)

Since physicalism comes in two flavors according to WP, it seems an adequate simplification to consider Chalmer's position a property-dualistic physicalism (although, a philosophy of mind scholar is welcome to provide better references):

In philosophy, physicalism is the view that "everything is physical", that there is "nothing over and above" the physical, or that everything supervenes on the physical (emphasis mine).

Furthermore, Dualism and Mind (IEP) claims:

Property dualists claim that mental phenomena are non-physical properties of physical phenomena, but not properties of non-physical substances. Property dualists are not committed to the existence of non-physical substances, but are committed to the irreducibility of mental phenomena to physical phenomena. (emphasis mine)

So, while I'm setting out to read Henry Taylor's analysis called "Powerful qualities, the conceivability argument and the nature of the physical" (springer.com), I pose this question: Why is Chalmer's naturalistic dualism not a form of non-reductive physicalism?
See also:

Chalmer's "Consciousness and It's Place in Nature".
What is David Chalmers' Naturalistic dualism? (PhilSE)
Why does Chalmers' argument about "the hard problem" not entail idealism? (PhilSE)


@Rushi Okay, this is the best way to resolve your objection. Feel free to clear the darkness from my mind.

Because he denies that mental properties reduce to physical ones even ontologically. Non-reductive physicalists hold that they do in some sense (in "god's eye" as it where) while epistemological reduction is impossible in principle for some cognitive reasons.

It has been a while since I read Chalmers' book on consciousness, but my recollection is that he to a degree left open aspects of how consciousness relates to the physical.  He primarily argued that consciousness did not reduce to the physical, but I do not think he committed between:

Emergent epiphenomenal dualism
Intrinsic epiphenomenal property dualism
Intrinsic non-interactive Russelian monism with dual properties

He did note that the last two imply pan-psychism.
I tend to agree with you that there is little difference between emergent or property dualism, and emergent physicalism, particularly if one cripples the dualism with epiphenomenalism.  The bright boundaries between different ideas do not always stay bright in the thinking of out of the box philosophers.
At the time that Chalmers wrote, there were a lot of physicalist philosophers condemning epiphenomenalism as a form of dualism, so his arguing for epiphenomenalism put him solidly in the "dualism" camp, as well as the "bad/condemn" camp.  Chalmers academic chops played a major role in philosophy of mind thinking subsequently reopening to forms of dualism, idealism, Russelian Monism, pan-psychism, etc.
Within this broader spectrum of approaches to mind, lumping emergent physicalism with emergent dualism, property dualism, and dual aspect monism as very related views, with two major versions of each based on interactionism or epiphenomenalism, as fairly different from IT or reductionist views, and fairly different from substance dualism, strikes me as reasonable.
